# Why I can't get the new view added in the ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm newer to ASP.NET Core applications and I'm trying to add a view, so I've added a function `MYName()` in `HomeController.cs` and I have created a view by clicking on `MYName()` function and choosing "Details" as a template

Unfortunately, I didn't get anything in the header of the page.

How can I create a new tab in the header called `MYName` side by side `Privacy` tab??

```
// ....  other code

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult MYName()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**MYName.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MYName";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p> My Name is Mohamed </p>
```

[image]

**Update :**

When I use visit this link ( rooting ) `https://.../Home/MYName`

I get the content of the page, but what I need exactly is adding a tab called `MYName` in the header.

Comment: How is the header being generated? Is there a layout or header file?

Comment: The header is automatically generated when you're creating new project on `.net`

Comment: @新Acesyyy and this is a good advantage of using ASP NET Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header can be updated via the shared _Layout.cshtml file.
Change this code to reflect:

```
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MYName">My Name</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0